# Rigidbody2D is working slower on heavy lag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D platformer movement using Rigidbody2D, and I noticed a strange thing:

If my FPS is normal, then the jumping works as expected. But if my FPS is really low (Maybe 5 fps, maybe less) then the player starts to jump extremely high. It seems like it's something to do with Rigidbody2D removing velocity much slower when it lags.

Code:

```cs
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerMovement _playerMovement;
    private InputAction _moveAction;

    private Vector2 _moveVec;
    private Rigidbody2D _rb;
    
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;

    [SerializeField] private float speed = 5.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight = 8.0f;

    private bool _jump;
    private bool _jumpHold;
    private bool _isJumping;
    private int _jumpTime = 0;
    private int _maxJumpTime = 40;

    private void Awake() {
        _playerMovement = new PlayerMovement();
    }

    private void Start() {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void OnEnable() {
        _playerMovement.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable() {
        _playerMovement.Disable();
        _playerMovement.Dispose();
    }

    private bool isGrounded() => Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 0.6f, groundLayer) 
                              || Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(transform.position.x - 0.5f, transform.position.y), Vector3.down, 0.6f, groundLayer) 
                              || Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(transform.position.x + 0.5f, transform.position.y), Vector3.down, 0.6f, groundLayer);

    private void Update() {

        if(_playerMovement.Movement.Jumping.WasPerformedThisFrame() && isGrounded())
        {
            _isJumping = true;
        }

        if (_playerMovement.Movement.Jumping.WasReleasedThisFrame()) _isJumping = false;

        if(_playerMovement.Movement.Jumping.IsPressed() && _isJumping) {
            if(_jumpTime>0) {
                _rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpHeight;
                _jumpTime--;
            }
            else {
                _isJumping = false;
            }

        }

        if (isGrounded()) _jumpTime = _maxJumpTime;
        if (!_playerMovement.Movement.Jumping.IsPressed()) _isJumping = false;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        Vector2 inp = _playerMovement.Movement.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        _rb.velocity = new Vector2(inp.x * speed , _rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix this, or do I just have to accept that that's how physics are gonna work on low FPS.

Comment: There's a lot of hard to see pitfalls in movement systems where the input comes in Update and executed in FixedUpdate. It's the right way to do things, but bug prone. Investigating if something wrong happens particularly in the edge cases where there are many FixedUpdates between two Updates, or many Updates between two FixedUpdates, could help you find your issue. That said, check out the Time settings, particularly Maximum Allowed Timestep. It may be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem depends on the updates per second in FixedUpdate when your FPS are low. This causes the speed to drop slower than intended, increasing the jump height.

Try using the following function to adjust the physics update interval to the frame rate:

```
private void FixedUpdate() {
  Vector2 inp = _playerMovement.Movement.Move.ReadValue < Vector2 > ();
  _rb.velocity = new Vector2(inp.x * speed * Time.deltaTime, _rb.velocity.y);
}
```

Comment: Making FixedUpdate framerate-dependent defeats the point of FixedUpdate. That said, Time.deltaTime returns Time.fixedDeltaTime when called from FixedUpdate, so this code doesn't make FixedUpdate framerate-dependent.